# Asymptotic behavior of modified Bessel function help

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions, gamma-function, bessel-functions

The modified Bessel function of the first kind is defined as

$$I_q(\rho)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)^{2m+q}}{m!\Gamma(m+q+1)}$$ where $\rho \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and $q \in \mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $q,\rho \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $\rho>0$, $q \geq 0$. I need help to prove the behavior
$$I_q(\rho )\approx \frac{e^{\rho}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \rho}}\,\,\,\text{as}\,\,\, \rho \to \infty$$

I tried using Stirling's approximation formula for the gamma function, but the general term inside the sum becomes so hard that I don't know to evaluate the series. I just need ideas on how to approach the calculation of this limit. Thank you.

**Observation:** In the above only the principal argument is considered and I'm trying to avoid (if possible) using integral representation of modified Bessel functions to prove the behavior

Comment: The limit is $0$ and not $\infty$, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.30.E4 Btw, $\rho<0$ should be avoided in the definition due to the ambigous powers if $q$ is not an integer.

Comment: I will write in a more precise way

Comment: One more $x$ there.

Comment: sorry, is $\rho$.

Comment: Do you know Watson's lemma, the Laplace's method or the saddle point method?

Comment: I don't know this methods, sorry :(

Comment: I know the Watson's lemma, but I don't know how to apply in the context of a function with series representation.

Comment: If you don't know these and don't want to rely on integral representations, you will have a hard time proving the asymptotics. Even if you do it via the sum, you will probably need to do a discrete saddle point approximation.

Comment: I think I will try learn how to prove the integral representations, can you recommend me a good book to learn how to prove the integral representations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136367/discussion-between-victor-rafael-and-gary).

Comment: Avoiding integral representations looks like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_walking) here.